# How to pass a header to a get request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, header, get-request

I am learning web dev, and I would like to pass an "authorization" header when a get request is made in the "/" route.

index.js:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("algoritmika", {logged: VefiryLogin(req)}); 
});
```

The "VerifyLogin" method expects a request with an "authorization" header, which is obvioulsy not passed in. I use Ajax to make post requests, but I do not know how to pass a header with a get request.

If I write my own Ajax get request for the "/" route and pass the headers, the "app.get" triggers twice, so the page doesn't get rendered correctly.

EDIT:
Ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')},
        success: function() { ... }
     });
```

EDIT 2:
More code and what I am trying to do (like I said, I am new to this so I don't know if this is the correct way):

Validate.js - this handles login and registration forms on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')},
        success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
     });

  $("#prijava").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
      },
    },
    messages: {
      email: {
        required: "Vnesite email",
        email: "Vnesite pravilni email",
      },
      password: {
        required: "Vnesite geslo",
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/prijava",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (token) {
          $(form).html("<div id='message'>Prijava uspela</div>");
          localStorage.setItem("token", token);
          setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
          }, 0001);
        },
        statusCode: {
          500: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseJSON);
            if (!$("#message").length) {
              $(form).append(
                "<div class='text-center' id='message'>" +
                  data.responseJSON.error +
                  "</div>"
              );
            }
          },
        },
      });
      return false;
    },
  });
  $("#registration").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
      },
    },
    messages: {
      email: {
        required: "Vnesite email",
        email: "Vnesite pravilni email",
      },
      password: {
        required: "Vnesite geslo",
        minlength: "Vnesite vsaj 8 znakov",
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      console.log($(form).serialize());
      console.log(form);
      console.log(JSON.stringify($(form).serialize()));
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/registracija",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          $(form).html("<div >Registracija uspela!</div>");
          setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
          }, 0001);
        },
        statusCode: {
          500: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseJSON);
            if (!$("#message2").length) {
              $(form).append(
                "<div class='text-center' id='message2'>" +
                  data.responseJSON.error +
                  "</div>"
              );
            }
          },
        },
      });
      return false;
    },
  });
});
```

start.js: this blocks the user from starting if they are not logged in.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startButton").on("click", function btnClick() {
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/start",
        headers: {"authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')},
        success: function (data) {

          if(data == false){
            $("#modalPrijava").modal("show")
          }
          else if(data == true){
            window.location.href = "/bubblesort";  
          }


        },
        fail: function (err) {
           console.log(err)


        }
      });
    });
  });
```

More of index.js - handles login verification.

```
app.get("/start", function (req, res) {
    VefiryLogin(req,res);
});

function VefiryLogin(req,res = null){


  return jwt.verify(req.headers["authorization"], SECRET_PW, function (
    err,
    decoded
  ) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error - not logged");
      console.log(err);
      SendIfNotNull(res,false);
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("no error");
      console.log(decoded._id);
      user = userModel.findById(decoded._id);

      if (user) {
        SendIfNotNull(res,true);
        return true;

      } else {
        console.log("no user with this id");
        SendIfNotNull(res,false);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}

function SendIfNotNull(res,value){
  if(res != null){
    res.send(value);
  }
}
```

algoritmika.ejs - displays different stuff if logged in or not

```
                            <% if(logged === false){ %>
                                ...
                            <% } else if(logged === true){ %>
                                ...
                            <% } %>
```

Comment: *"I use Ajax to make post requests, but I do not know how to pass a header with a get request."* The same way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If I write a custom Ajax get request for the "/" route, the get triggers twice, and the page doesn't get rendered correctly.

Comment: Please show your ajax code and we can advise on where to add the headers.   Also, it's a bit unclear that you're calling this route from Ajax, but the result of the route is a rendered HTML page?  What are you doing with that rendering page in the Ajax code?   Rendering twice sounds like some sort of problem on the client since the server doesn't do that on its own so we also need to see more client code to have any idea why it's doing that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't want it to render twice. The reason is that I want to check if the user is logged in with the token and I need to get it from local storage. Is there a different way to approach this? Also are you saying the page should not trigger the "app.get" on it's own after it has been loaded?

Comment: Too little context here to see the actual code flow.  Your ajax call looks like it's sending the ajax call just fine.  But, we can't see any code flow for how the page itself is loaded in the browser.  You should not be checking a token with an ajax call.  If the token is required in order to render the page, the token checking should be part of a middleware in the page rendering route, not a separate ajax call.  But, I can't really tell what your overall trying to do here.  I can tell something is wrong, but can't tell what the real end goal of all this code is.

Comment: You seem to want to give us little tiny bites of code here.  We can give you much higher level and more valuable answers if you give us the whole code flow so we can see what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  Start with what happens when a URL first gets put into the browser for your site. Explain exactly  what you want to have happen and show us all relevant code in that.

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope it is now clear what I want to do.

Comment: It's really odd to make an Ajax request to `/`. Are you simplifying the URL and hiding it being a cross-origin request?

Comment: @Quentin everything is just on one page - the login and register forms are in modals, and I would like this page to update once you login. I need this so that only those who are logged in can go to the other routes via a "start" button. Is this wrong?